# Ensure optimized parallel consumption from topic

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am very new to Kafka and I'll try to describe the problem I'm facing and the possible solution I am thinking of.

In my Node.js application, I have a chain of Kafka Topics (say 3) and each topic has a single consumer and single partitions as well. The reason I chose single partition is because order of operations is very important to me and I don't want disordering of messages due to rebalancing or something.

Now, there are 2 users simultaneously doing some asynchronous operations. Let's assume the operations are being done continuously one after the other. User1 does 5000 operations. While the user1 has already started bombarding the topics, the second user decides to do 5 continuous operations as well.

My observation is, if an operation takes around ~5secs, user2's operations are taking way more than 5seconds, in worst cases even 30-45 seconds. This should be happening parallelly as there can be more than 2 users at a time.

I am thinking of implementing a **message-keyed partitioning** to cater this issue. I mean I'll have a hash function that'll give a constant upon hashing the userID and this constant will decide the partition for a user and will hence ensure ordering as well. My queries with this approach are:

- What if I decide to add more partitions in future?
- How will I make single consumer listen from different partitions. Will I need multiple consumers?
- The same hashing and message-keyed partitioning has to happen for all 3 topics, right?

**Please let me know if I am moving in the right direction or if you have any suggestions. Do let me know if I need to elaborate my question or use-case.**

Answer (score 0):

> decide to add more partitions in future

You'll lose ordering. Existing data will stay in its existing, single partition. New data will arrive in a computed partition

> make single consumer listen from different partitions

This is automatic, but multiple consumers would help

> same hashing and message-keyed partitioning has to happen for all 3 topics, right?

That's not a requirement unless you were to use Kafka Streams, where the partition counts need to be the same between joined topics, for example

---

Partitioning by users isn't a good idea unless you have a fixed number of them. For example, rather than one partition per user, you could give each a numeric ID, then use 10 partitions to designate the first number in that ID. Otherwise, partitioning by "operation" and including user information in the event may work better, though depends on your ordering requirements.